# Generate pdf from a function of jquery and want to save it on my server

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate the pdf using jquery function and want to save it on server

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
var doc = new jsPDF();

doc.fromHTML(jQuery('#finalOutput').html(), 15, 15, {
    'width': 180,
}, function () {
    doc.save('sample-file-1.pdf');

});
```

this is my code i'm using how can i save it on server also i want to save all the things into  database like the file name and path where client download it

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating your pdf on the client, you need to "push" it to the server to store.

This means you need:

1. an "end-point" on the server that you can call to send the file and the other properties (name, path etc) you mentioned
2. to write the code to do the push from the client. This would typically be a straight forward HTTP post which is not hard from jQuery.

If you are actually using WordPress (indicated by the tags), you'll need to find out if / how it lets you store files and / or have a database.

I hope that helps.